# Make conditionalPanel depend on files uploaded with fileInput

Tags: r, shiny

So I'm trying to make a shiny app where I have a button which only shows up if files have been uploaded; for this im using conditionalPanel.

ui.R:

```
require(shiny)
shinyUI(pageWithSidebar(
  headerPanel("My App"),

  sidebarPanel(
    fileInput("files", "Choose file"),
    conditionalPanel(
      condition = "input.files",
      actionButton("submitFiles", "Submit files for processing"))),

  mainPanel(h3("Nothing to see here"))
))
```

I don't think there's anything to care about in my server.R, since the above example doesn't *do* anything. With the above condition, the button never shows up, i.e. the condition is never true.

Some things I've tried for my condition are `input.files.length > 0`, `input.files.size() > 0`, both of which result in the button being present *before* I upload a file. I'm guessing this is because input$files is an empty data.frame before choosing files, and so has a non-zero length/size, is that right?

What condition can I use to hide the button until at least one file is done uploading?

I think another option would be to replace `conditionalPanel` with `uiOutput`, and call `renderUI({actionButton(...)})` inside of an observe/isolate block in server.R which is watching input.files (`if (nrow(input$files) < 1) return()`); is that the only way? If I can do this either way, what would make me pick one or the other (beyond `conditionalPanel` resulting in less code)?

Answer (score 58, accepted):

You have to make a reactive output returning the status of the uploading and set the option `suspendWhenHidden` of this output to `FALSE`.

More precisely, in *server.R* you surely have a reactive function, say `getData()` to make a dataframe from the uploaded file. Then do this:

```
  getData <- reactive({
    if(is.null(input$files)) return(NULL)
    ......
  })
  output$fileUploaded <- reactive({
    return(!is.null(getData()))
  })
  outputOptions(output, 'fileUploaded', suspendWhenHidden=FALSE)
```

And in *ui.R* you can use `conditionalPanel()` by doing:

```
conditionalPanel("output.fileUploaded",
   ......
```

Comment: aha, I didn't even know `outputOptions()` existed! That's a tricky way to 'hide' something in your `output` list, but it works.

Comment: It seems that something has changed and now one has to do `"output.fileUploaded == true"`.

Comment: Since all-caps `TRUE` is normally used in R, I feel like I should point out that the lowercase `true` used in `"output.fileUploaded == true"` is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Under R 4.2.2, I have to changed it to `"output.fileUploaded == 0"` to make it work. I do not know why.