# Numeric output value as condition for conditionalPanel

Tags: r, shiny

What I really want to do is pass a numeric output condition for generating a conditional panel.  I can't seem to render an output as numeric though.

My work around was to generate a reactive using the numeric condition of interest and pass that to the conditional panel as text.  However, I'm struggling with this as well.

Below is an example:

the goal being to open a conditional panel whenever the user enters a number that when multiplied by 5 is greater than 100 
YES - I know I could do this by setting input$number >20
This is a simplified example of what I'm working on.
The issue is using numeric OUTPUT for a conditional panel

Thanks!

Sam

```
library(shiny)

shinyApp(
  ui = fluidPage(
    fluidRow(
            wellPanel(
              numericInput("number", label = "Choose a Number between -100 and 100", 
                           min = -100, max = 100, value = 0))),
    fluidRow(wellPanel(textOutput("text_out"))),
    fluidRow(conditionalPanel(
      condition = "output.big == '1' ", 
      fluidRow(h1("You've selected a number larger than 20!"))))),
  server = function(input, output, session){
    # I want to execute a function on a numeric input
    times_5<-reactive({ 
      input$number*5
      })   
    # I can't get the condition to work with a numeric query
    # So, I run the query on the server side and generate an if/else statement 
    # to pass a text variable
    over_100<-reactive({
      if(times_5()>100){
        return(1)
      } else{
        return(0)
      }
    })

    output$text_out<-renderText({
       paste("This is text out put of the number ", input$number, "multiplied by 5 to equal ", times_5(), over_100())
    })
    # I can't find a render function that generates numeric output
    # Even still this outputtext doesn't seem to work in the conditional statement.
    output$big<-renderText({
      over_100
    })
  }
)
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At first it seems that [Shiny needs to have the value displayed](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21609436/r-shiny-conditionalpanel-output-value) to use it in a condition, but this is not actually true:

```
outputOptions(output, 'big', suspendWhenHidden=FALSE)
```

You will tell Shiny to consider that value also when it's not visible.

Even if you add this line in your server function, you need another change: the value of big needs to be calculated, so this:

```
output$big<-renderText({
  over_100
})
```

has to become this:

```
output$big<-renderText(over_100())
```

Hope this can help you.

Comment: Thank you!  I keep forgetting the () when I call a reactive.  The outputOptions was just what I needed.

Comment: outputOptions(output, 'big', suspendWhenHidden=FALSE) is such a biggie. Thanks @mucio .