# Shiny Conditional Panel (ELSE Statement?)

Tags: r, shiny, conditional-statements

I am trying to have text show when the Selector equals a page (i.e. number) in the code and default to another text when not specified. Would it be possible to use an ELSE statement in the code to condition this?

```
conditionalPanel("input.MPDDSelector == 13 || input.MPDDSelector == 17 || input.MPDDSelector == 21",  
    strong("%D2 Growth")),




    #Need to make this the default for 1-12, 14-16, 18-20, 22-30#
    strong("Year-Over-Year Growth"),
```

Comment: use another condition panel instead of using else

Comment: Is there a way to avoid writing a conditional statement using 27 other "input.MPDDSelector =="

Comment: It is possible to use `output.outputid` in the `conditionalPanel`s conditions. See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21609436/r-shiny-conditionalpanel-output-value)