# r shiny: make fileInput widget disappear after file input

Tags: r, widget, shiny

could I make fileInput widget disappear after file input? Or could I get rid of the blue progress bar?

Thank you!

Comment: Please provide a minimal reproducible example that illustrates the issue you are having.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hello Stéphane Laurent answered a similar question [in this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19686581/make-conditionalpanel-depend-on-files-uploaded-with-fileinput), with a minimal example it gives :

```
data("kyphosis", package = "rpart")
write.table(kyphosis, file = "kyphosis.txt", row.names = FALSE)


library(shiny)
runApp(list(
  ui = pageWithSidebar(
    headerPanel = headerPanel(" "),
    sidebarPanel = sidebarPanel( conditionalPanel(condition = "output.fileUploaded",
                                                  fileInput(inputId = "file_input", label = "Input" ) )),
    mainPanel = mainPanel( tableOutput(outputId = "table"))
  ),
  server = function(input, output) {

  getData <- reactive({
    if(is.null(input$file_input)) {
      return(NULL)
    } else {
      return(read.table(input$file_input$datapath, header = TRUE))
    }
  })

  output$fileUploaded <- reactive({
    return(is.null(getData()))
  })

  output$table <- renderTable({
    head(getData())
  })
  outputOptions(output, 'fileUploaded', suspendWhenHidden=FALSE)
  }
))
```