# conditionalPanel in Shiny causes the selectInput to fail

Tags: r, shiny

I am stumped on why my `selectInput` doesn't work.

After including a `conditionalPanel`, suddenly switching out names from John Doe to Joe Blow in the `selectInput` no longer works -- the dates don't update and the map goes grey.

I don't understand why this is happening. The only way it does work is if I click on `no_date` then go back and change the name. Then things fire. But I can't figure out why/how this is broken.

Initially, things are fine:

[image]

But when I select Joe Blow:

[image]

Notice the date doesn't change.

There is something strange going on with the `conditionalPanel` but for the life of me I'm stuck. Thanks for reading this.

**UI.R**

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)


DF <- data.frame(lon=c(-120.6596156, -87.27751, -119.7725868, -124.2026, -117.1858759),  
                 lat=c(35.2827524, 33.83122, 36.7468422, 41.75575, 34.5008311), 
                 date=c('2014-03-14', '2014-01-11', '2013-11-22', '2012-08-23', '2013-08-23'),
                 city=c('San Luis Obispo', 'Jasper', 'Fresno', 'Crescent City', 'Apple Valley'), 
                 P1_name=c('John Doe', 'John Doe', 'John Doe', 'John Doe', 'Joe Blow'))

DF[, c('date', 'city', 'P1_name')] <- sapply(DF[, c('date', 'city', 'P1_name')], as.character)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$fdate<-renderUI({
    selectInput('dates', 'Select date', choices=DF[which(DF$P1_name == input$person), ]$date, selectize = FALSE)
  })

  output$map<-renderLeaflet({
    DF <- filter(DF, P1_name==input$person, date==input$dates)    
    output$city <-renderText({c("Location:", DF$city)})


    m <- leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
      setView(lng=DF$lon, lat=DF$lat, zoom=5) %>%
      addMarkers(lng=DF$lon, lat=DF$lat, popup=DF$city)

  })

}

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Testing Shiny"),
  sidebarLayout (
    sidebarPanel(

      selectInput('person', 'Select person', choices=unique(DF$P1_name), selectize = FALSE),

      radioButtons('radio', 'Select method', choices=c('show_date', 'no_date'), selected = NULL, inline = TRUE),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.radio == 'show_date'",
        uiOutput('fdate')

      ),

      textOutput("city")

    ),

    mainPanel(
      leafletOutput('map')
    )  
  ))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

Comment: Does [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/21535587/4002530) regarding `outputoptions` help?

Comment: Not sure how to use that solution in my problem...I'll keep working on it...thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Essentially output$fdate should be called the same name as 'dates'

```
library(shiny)
library(ggplot2)
library(dplyr)
library(leaflet)


DF <- data.frame(lon=c(-120.6596156, -87.27751, -119.7725868, -124.2026, -117.1858759),  
                 lat=c(35.2827524, 33.83122, 36.7468422, 41.75575, 34.5008311), 
                 date=c('2014-03-14', '2014-01-11', '2013-11-22', '2012-08-23', '2013-08-23'),
                 city=c('San Luis Obispo', 'Jasper', 'Fresno', 'Crescent City', 'Apple Valley'), 
                 P1_name=c('John Doe', 'John Doe', 'John Doe', 'John Doe', 'Joe Blow'))

DF[, c('date', 'city', 'P1_name')] <- sapply(DF[, c('date', 'city', 'P1_name')], as.character)


server <- function(input, output, session) {

  output$dates<-renderUI({
    selectInput('dates', 'Select date', choices=DF[which(DF$P1_name == input$person), ]$date, selectize = FALSE)
  })

  output$map<-renderLeaflet({
    validate(
      need(!is.null(input$dates),""),
      need(!is.null(input$person),"")
    )
    DF <- filter(DF, P1_name==input$person, date==input$dates)    
    output$city <-renderText({c("Location:", DF$city)})


    m <- leaflet() %>%
      addTiles() %>%  # Add default OpenStreetMap map tiles
      setView(lng=DF$lon, lat=DF$lat, zoom=5) %>%
      addMarkers(lng=DF$lon, lat=DF$lat, popup=DF$city)

  })

}

ui <- fluidPage(
  titlePanel("Testing Shiny"),
  sidebarLayout (
    sidebarPanel(

      selectInput('person', 'Select person', choices=unique(DF$P1_name), selectize = FALSE),

      radioButtons('radio', 'Select method', choices=c('show_date', 'no_date'), selected = NULL, inline = TRUE),
      conditionalPanel(
        condition = "input.radio == 'show_date'",
        uiOutput('dates')

      ),

      textOutput("city")

    ),

    mainPanel(
      leafletOutput('map')
    )  
  ))

shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```