# Shiny failed to read column based on selectInput from uploaded csv

Tags: r, file-upload, dynamic, shiny, reactive

#### Problem:

I was trying to build a shiny app that plot frequency of n-grams based on a user specified column from a user uploaded csv. In addition, a function was added to plot the senetiment over time, based on a date column specified by the user as well.

The app was working okay locally, with Warning, but failed work after published.  Please see the following for a reproducible example.

#### Preparation: libraries and example data

```
# Load R packages
library(shiny)
library(tidyverse)
library(shinythemes)
library(lubridate)
library(tidytext)
library(textdata)

# Creating a example csv file for upload
Sample_csv <- 
  data.frame(text = janeaustenr::emma,
             id = 1:length(janeaustenr::emma),
             date = sample(seq(as.Date('1900/01/01'), as.Date('1920/01/01'), by="day"),
                           replace = T,
                           length(janeaustenr::emma)))
write.csv(Sample_csv, "Sample_csv.csv", row.names = F)
```

#### UI

```
ui <- fluidPage(theme = shinytheme("united"),
                titlePanel("Text glancer"),
                sidebarLayout(
                  sidebarPanel(
                    # Input: Select a file ----
                    fileInput("csv_file", "Feed csv here",
                              multiple = FALSE,
                              accept = c(".csv")),
                        #Conditional panel 
                    conditionalPanel(
                      # use a server side condition
                      condition = "output$fileUploaded",
                      # Input: Select  ----
                      uiOutput("text_select"),
                      # Input: Select  ----
                      uiOutput("date_select"),
                      # Input: Simple integer interval ----
                      sliderInput("top_frequency", "Top n ngrams to be plotted:",
                                  min = 5, max = 20, value = 10),
                      # Input: Select  ----
                      selectInput("ngrams", "Ngrams of your choice:",
                                  c("Single word" = 1,
                                    "Bigram" = 2,
                                    "Trigram" = 3)
                      )
                    ),
                    # Submit bottom
                    submitButton("Update View", icon("refresh"))
                  ), 
                  # sidebarPanel
                  mainPanel(
                    tabsetPanel(
                      tabPanel(h2("Most frequenlty used n-grams"),
                               plotOutput("frequency_plot", height = 900, width = 1200)),
                      tabPanel(h2("Sentiment of the months"),
                               plotOutput("sentiment_plot", height = 900, width = 1200))
                    )
                  )
                ) 
)
```

#### server

```
server <- function(input, output, session) {
  
  # create reactive version of the dataset (a data.frame object)
  LOAD_DATA <- reactive({
    infile <- input$csv_file
    if (is.null(infile)) 
    {return(NULL)}
    {read_csv(infile$datapath)}
  })
  
  
  # inform conditionalPanel wheter dropdowns sohould be hidden
  output$fileUploaded <- reactive({
    return(!is.null(LOAD_DATA()))
  })
  outputOptions(output, 'fileUploaded', suspendWhenHidden=FALSE)
  
  ## update 'column' selectors
  output$text_select <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(LOAD_DATA()))
    {return(NULL)}
    else
      selectInput("text_col", "Select the text column:", colnames(LOAD_DATA()))
  })
  
  output$date_select <- renderUI({
    if(is.null(LOAD_DATA()))
    {return(NULL)}
    else
      selectInput("date_col", "Select the date column (ymd):", colnames(LOAD_DATA())) 
  })
  
  # Create reactive parameters
  TOP_FREQUENCY <- reactive({
    input$top_frequency
  })
  N_GRAMS <- reactive({
    as.numeric(as.character(input$ngrams))
  })

  # Output frequency of ngrams
  output$frequency_plot <- renderPlot( {
    
    if(is.null(LOAD_DATA()))
    {return(NULL)}
    
    else{
      
      WORK_DATA <-  LOAD_DATA()[,c(input$text_col,
                                   input$date_col)]
      names(WORK_DATA) <- c("TEXTS", "DATES")
      
      CSV_DOC_N_Grams <-
        WORK_DATA %>%
        # LOAD_DATA() %>%
        # select(TEXTS = TEXT_COL(), DATES = DATE_COL()) %>%
        mutate(TEXTS = gsub("http.*", " ", TEXTS)) %>%
        # mutate(text = gsub("\\@.* |\\@.* .|\\@.* ,", " ", text)) %>%
        unnest_tokens(words, TEXTS, token = "ngrams", n = N_GRAMS()) %>%
        select(words) %>%
        filter(str_detect(words, "[a-zA-Z]")) %>%
        separate(words,  c("word1","word2","word3"),sep = " ", remove = F) %>%
        filter(! word1 %in% stop_words$word &
                 ! word2 %in% stop_words$word&
                 ! word3 %in% stop_words$word)
      
      #Counting ngrams
      CSV_DOC_N_Gramss_Count <-
        CSV_DOC_N_Grams %>%
        count(words, sort=T) %>%
        select(N_Gram_Text = words,
               N_Gram_Count = n)
      
      #Plotting ngram frequency
      CSV_DOC_N_Gramss_Count_freq <-
        CSV_DOC_N_Gramss_Count %>%
        mutate(N_Gram_Text = fct_reorder(N_Gram_Text, N_Gram_Count)) %>%
        top_n(TOP_FREQUENCY(), N_Gram_Count) %>%                          
        ggplot(aes(x = N_Gram_Text,
                   y = N_Gram_Count,
                   fill = N_Gram_Count)) +
        geom_col()+
        coord_flip() +
        scale_fill_gradient2()+
        labs(title = paste0("Top ", TOP_FREQUENCY(), " ngrams used in csv doc"),
             x = "ngrams",
             y = "frequency") +
        theme_bw()+
        theme(legend.position = "none",
              axis.text.x = element_text(face='bold',size=12),
              axis.text.y = element_text(face='bold',size=12),
              axis.title.x = element_text(face='bold',size=18),
              axis.title.y = element_blank())
      print(CSV_DOC_N_Gramss_Count_freq)
    }
  })
  
  
  output$sentiment_plot <- renderPlot( {
    
    if(is.null(LOAD_DATA())){return(NULL)}
    
    else{
      
      WORK_DATA <-  LOAD_DATA()[,c(input$text_col,
                                   input$date_col)]
      names(WORK_DATA) <- c("TEXTS", "DATES")
      
      tk_afinn <-
        WORK_DATA %>%
        mutate(TEXTS = gsub("http.*", " ", TEXTS)) %>%
        unnest_tokens(word, TEXTS) %>%
        filter(! word %in% stop_words$word) %>%
        filter(str_detect(word, "[a-zA-Z]")) %>%
        filter(! DATES %in% NA) %>%
        inner_join(get_sentiments("afinn")) %>%
        mutate(YEAR_Month = ymd(paste(year(DATES),
                                      month(DATES),
                                      "1", sep="-"))) %>%
        group_by(index = YEAR_Month) %>%
        summarise(sentiment = sum(value))
      
      tk_afinn_plot <-
        tk_afinn  %>%
        ggplot(aes(x = index, y = sentiment)) +
        geom_line()+
        labs(x = "date (year-month)",
             y = "sentiment of the month") +
        theme_bw()+
        theme(legend.position = "none",
              axis.text.x = element_text(face='bold',size=12),
              axis.text.y = element_text(face='bold',size=12),
              axis.title.x = element_text(face='bold',size=18),
              axis.title.y = element_blank())
      print(tk_afinn_plot)
    }
  })
}
```

#### Fuse

```
shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

#### Warnings:

After loading the csv file, the local app reports :
"Problem with `mutate()` input `TEXTS`.
object 'TEXTS' not found
Input `TEXTS` is `gsub("http.*", " ", TEXTS)`."

After specify the text column and date column, both tab showed plots. However, after publishing it to shinyapp.io, it reports error and would not run.

Can anybody help with this issue?  I have consulted the other thread includin this>https://stackoverflow.com/questions/47248534/dynamically-list-choices-for-selectinput-from-a-user-selected-column, but still no luck.

Any insight would be greatly appreciated!

Comment: What is the size of your file? I read shinyaps.io is limited to 32MB.

Comment: Hi Hubert, thank you for your question.  The original file I tried was smaller than 32MB, and the sample set should also be less than 2MB. However, the app still reports an error.

Comment: Hi  Yayi Zhao,  is it still not OK?

Comment: Unfortunately, it still does not work, even with small sized data.