# shiny conditionpanel output value

Tags: r, shiny, output, conditional-statements

everyone, I want to use the output value to control a conditionalPanel in a shiny app. The following is my code,

```
ui = fluidPage(
navbarPage(title = "Test", 
           id = "test",
           navbarMenu(
             title = "One step analysis",
             icon = icon(name = "paper-plane"),
             tabPanel("Data cleaning",
                      value = "one.dc",
                      conditionalPanel(
                        condition = "output.id==1",
                        # source("ui/emailInputUI.R", local = TRUE)$value
                        "test"
                      )
             )
             )
           )
           )


server = function(input, output) {
output$id<-reactive({0})
 }

  shinyApp(ui = ui, server = server)
```

However, it didn'r work, anyone can help me? Thank you very mcuh!

Comment: set your condition to `"output.id==0"` and add `outputOptions(output, "id", suspendWhenHidden = FALSE)` to your server and it will work.

Comment: @BigDataScientist is right. See an example here: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/19686581/make-conditionalpanel-depend-on-files-uploaded-with-fileinput/21535587#21535587

Comment: Thank you very much for your nice and helpful answer!